# logarithm express $q^{q+2}$ in term of $p$.

Tags: logarithms

Given $p=3^q$, express $q^{q+2}$  in terms of $p$.

I only performed until here, but the answer given is $81p^2$. I've no idea how to continue then.

${log_3p}^{log_3p+2}={log_3p^{log_3p}}{{log_3p}^2}$

Comment: i changed q=log_3⁡p, then substitute back. log_3⁡p^(log_3⁡p+2)
then i don't know how to continue

Comment: $(\log_3⁡p)^2 + \log_3 p^2 $

Comment: Why would you continue?This should be enough

Comment: because the answer given is $81p^2$

Comment: the answer only valid when $q=9$, then $9^{9+2}=81(3^9)^2$. thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well $q = \log_3 p$ so ... what more do you need to be able to do this?

Comment: because the answer given is $81p2$

Comment: The book answer is obviously wrong.  If q = 1 then p =3 and $1^{1+2} = 1 \ne 81*3^2$.  You should have told us that you were having trouble an answer and told us what the answer said.

Comment: sorry for didn't mention the answer at the first place. you're right, the answer only valid when $q=9$, then $9^{9+2}=81(3^9)^2$